# How to use the spread operator to flatten array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects [{x:0, y:1}, {x:3, y:2}] in javascript.

I want to to get an array of x only (0, 3) using the spread operator ...
so I can apply javascript Math.max after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to spread, though, you want to map (and then spread the result). So do that:

```
Math.max(...input.map(_=>_.x));
```

Comment: Thank you, I try to assign this expression to a variable then find the max and min but it tells me it is a syntax error.

var vector = ...input.map(_=>_.x)
Math.max(vector)
Math.min(vector)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 lambda function to achieve this. Please refer code below.

```js
var input = [{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":3,"y":5},{"x":2,"y":2}];
console.log( Math.max( ...input.map(function(a){return a.x} ) ) );
```

Comment: How is this different than what is already posted? Please don't add unnecessary noise. And there is no *lambda function* in your code.